# Checkbox doesn't store the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a dynamic Question List along with its dynamic options. With each option I maintain a flag using checkbox. If the checkbox is clicked the `AnalysisFlag` value should be `true` and if not then it should be `false`. However using the below mentioned method, I am always getting the `false` value whether I clicked the checkbox or not.

Can someone please take a look and suggest me how I can maintain the `AnalysisFlag` value along with its equivalent option?

```js
function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
        var textBox = $("<input />").attr("type", "textbox").attr("name", "DynamicTextBox").attr("class", "form-control").attr("placeholder","Your Answer");
    textBox.val(value);
    debugger;
    **var allVals = [];
    $('[name="DynamicAnalysisFlag"]:checked').each(function () {
        allVals.push($(this).val());
    });**

    return textBox, allVals;
}

var j = 66;
var x = 2;
var option = 'option' + x;

function AddTextBox() {
  for (var i = j; i <= j; i++) {
    $('#TextBoxContainer' + x).after("<br id='Removebr" + (x + 1) + "'><div class='input-group' id='TextBoxContainer" + (x + 1) + "'><div class= 'input-group-prepend'><div class='input-group-text'> " + String.fromCharCode(i) + " &nbsp; **<input type='checkbox' id='DynamicAnalysisFlag' value= 'true' name='DynamicAnalysisFlag' class='checklistitem''></div>**</div><input autocomplete='off' class='form-control test-option test-option" + x + "  text-box single-line' data-val='true' data-val-required='Answer is required' id=" + option + " name='DynamicTextBox' placeholder='Your Answer' type='text' value=''><span class='field-validation-valid text-danger' data-valmsg-for='AnalysisFlag' data-valmsg-replace='true'></span></div>");
  }
  j++;
  x++;
}

function RemoveTextBox() {
  if (x != 2) {
    $('#TextBoxContainer' + x).remove();
    $('#Removebr' + x).remove();
    --x;
    --j;
  }
}

$('#btnNext').on('click', function() {
  var radioValue1 = $("input[name='AnalysisFlag']:checked").val();
  var txtVal = $('.test-option' + radioValue1).val();
  $('#hiddenRadioValue').val(txtVal);
});

$(function() {
  var values = eval('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Values)');
  if (values != null) {
    $("#TextBoxContainer").html("");
    $(values).each(function() {
      $("#TextBoxContainer").append(GetDynamicTextBox(this));
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="radio" class="col-xs-12">
                <br id="Removebr2">
                <div class="input-group" id="TextBoxContainer2">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            A &nbsp;
                            <input type="checkbox" id="radio1" value="1" name="AnalysisFlag" onselect="alert('clicke')">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control test-option test-option1  text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="Option is required" id="opt1" name="opt1" placeholder="Your Answer" type="text" value="">
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="opt1" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The AnalysisFlag field is required." id="hiddenRadioValue" name="AnalysisFlag" type="hidden" value="">
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
<div class="card-footer">
                <input type="submit" id="btnNext" value="Next »" class="btn btn-primary vigor-btn">
            </div>
<button type="button" id="btnRemove" class="btn btn-primary vigor-btn" onclick="RemoveTextBox()">Remove Options</button>
<button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-primary vigor-btn" onclick="AddTextBox()">Add Options</button>
```

I have edited the `GetDynamicTextBox()` function in which I am getting the DynamicAnalysisFlag value which I add at the time of adding another textbox in `AddTextBox()` function. But now the issue is, if I tick the checkbox I am getting the true value but if I don't tick the checkbox I am getting nothing. So, what changes should I do in this code so if I check the code, I get true and if not then I get false.

Comment: As the Razor code isn't relevant to the problem, can you please edit the question to include the HTML output so that we can create a working example of the issue. Also note that using `eval()` is a massive code smell. I'm not sure why you're doing that, but it's incredibly bad practice and needs to be removed.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for editing and looking into this. I have edited the code with HTML output. Also, I will surely take a look into and try to remove the `eval()` and find its alternative.

Comment: Why do you need to use js and hidden fields for the purpose? A simple asp.net MVC flow can serve the purpose. You just need to render the html and catch the values in the action. Check box will only send data if ticked. So in your action if you have a bool value called AnalysisFlag will catch the `true` value if checked otherwise false. Coming back to dynamic question-answer, do you render one question and its options at a time or multiple questions and their options at the same time?

Comment: @rahatur I am rendering one question and its multiple options at a time. But, I need to manage the AnalysisFlag value equivalent for each option.